# How to use django social media icons instead of link_text

Tags: django

I am trying to use `django-social-media` share buttons. The share link comes with text instead of social media icons such as facebook, linkedin and twitter. How can i display the icons instead of "Post to FaceBook" text link?

```
<a href="#!">
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
<i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:#4267B2"></i>
<i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>{% post_to_facebook object_or_url %}
</span>
</a>
<a href="{{ linkedin_url }}">
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
<i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color: #0e76a8"></i>
<i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>{% post_to_linkedin object_or_url %}
</span>
</a>
<a href="#!">
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
<i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color: #1DA1F2"></i>
<i class="fab fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>{% post_to_twitter "New Article: {{object.title}}. Check it out!" object_or_url %}
</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

What eventually worked was, making a template folder with identical folder structure with django-social-share templates under project folder and customize the template.
Twitter and Facebook worked but not LinkedIn.

```
<div class="tweet-this">
    <a href="{{ tweet_url }}" class="meta-act-link meta-tweet {{link_class}}" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square" style="color: #1DA1F2" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{link_text}}</a>
</div>
```